# How to make visibility of row false in case of mozilla firefox?

Tags: asp.net

I have taken table inside that i have taken the row. in design mode when i make the visibility of row as false then there is pair of line comes which represents like there is row.

How to make this line invisible when row visibility is false.

In case of Internet  explorer the pair of line not come when rows visibility is false. same things i want to do with  mozilla firefox .How to do that?

Comment: Any one who can give the answer of this question........

Comment: @Shalni do you use jQuery or other ? - a code of you may help more.

Comment: I have use css and html.

Comment: @Shalni if its urgent then you need to give the code of your problem and how you make visible or not the rows.

Comment: <tr visible =false> then it is not visible in case of internet explorer but  visible in case of mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shalni from the line you say , you need to do it

```
<tr visible="false" runat="server" id="tr1">
```

on code behind

```
tr1.visible=true;
```

Comment: This permanently make invisible to that row but i have to make it invisible in certain condition. so i have to make it invisible according to the condition.

Comment: @Shalni you place an id to the tr, and you change it.